# Display all the lines in grepFile that do not start with a letter

Tags: files, grep

I want a universal way of displaying all the lines in grepFile that do not start with a letter.

Answer (score 3):

Easy enough: `grep -v '^[[:alpha:]]' testfile`

with a testfile like this one:

```bash
$ cat testfile 
sfdsaf
1sdflad
 asfd
,asdfasdf
safdaf
```

The above command will return:

```bash
$ grep -v '^[[:alpha:]]' testfile 
1sdflad
 asfd
,asdfasdf
```

**Why?**

- `^` greps the beginning of a line
- `[[:alpha:]]` greps for 1 letter
- `-v` inverts the match

**An alternative** would be using `sed '/^[[:alpha:]]/d' testfile`, where `sed`'s `d` command deletes everything that matches `^[[:alpha:]]` --which again is a letter at the start of the line.

**Another alternative** is `awk '/^[^a-zA-Z]/ { print $0 }' testfile`

Comment: Also `grep '^[^[:alpha:]]'` which would get rid of empty lines (if these are wanted or not is not clear).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the regex option in grep and inverse the output of finding a letter as the first character:

```
$ cat file.txt

asd
Ajnjn
bdfadsf
Bkkkknm
csdgadga
4gafga
dfsdf
esdfasdg
2fsefse
~asdasd
 dfdfsd
fartaherh
3adsfasdf

$ grep -ve '^[a-zA-Z]' file.txt

4gafga
2fsefse
~asdasd
 dfdfsd
3adsfasdf
```

Comment: `^` is special in many shells (Bourne, fish, rc, es, zsh -o extendedglob) and would need to be quoted there.

Comment: `[...]` is special in all shells but `fish`. For instance, in `bash` if there were files called `^a` and `^Z`, that `^[a-zA-Z]` would expand to both filenames. Again, you'd want to quote it.

Comment: What character or sequence of character (collating element) `[a-zA-Z]` matches varies with the locale and is probably not what you want outside of the C locale. You'd want to use `LC_ALL=C grep -v '^[a-zA-Z]'` to match only on US-ASCII English letters (though if the file.txt was encoded in some multibyte charset, it could end-up match parts of some characters), or `grep -v '^[[:alpha:]]` to match on any alphabetic collating element in your locale.

Comment: All very true, and in that case [this is the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/539114/366597) that should be marked correct, and I'm upvoting for taking a lot more into account.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with below command too

command1:

```
sed -n '/^[a-zA-Z]/!p'  testfile
```

command2:

```
awk '$0 !~ /^[a-zA-Z]/{print $0}' testfile
```

Comment: What about upper-case letters? Note also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418247/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105784/117549